# How to create a 2d color map plot from x and y coordinates and a vector of values?

Tags: matlab, plot, 2d, colormap

I'm trying to plot a 2 dimensional signal on a specific plane in a 3d model. I have the matrix:

xyzp (nx3)

that contains all the points which are closest to the plane (e.g. when the plane is in the z direction, all the z coordinates are fairly similar).
and I have a vector:

signal (nx1)

that contains a value for each point in xyzp.
when I use:
"surf([xyzp(:,[1,2]),signal)" or "mesh([xyzp(:,[1,2]),signal])"
The plot I get doesn't look at all like the intersection of the plane with the model from any angle (I expected "view(2)" to show the signal in the Z direction), so I assume I didn't use the plot function correctly.

Can anyone show me an example? For instance - A circle on an xy plane with some random signal indicated by color

Comment: Does `xyzp` just contain a list of x-y-z coordinates that correspond per row to the values in signal? Also do the points form an ordered grid or are they arbitrarily placed?

Comment: They are arbitrarily placed, and yes, they correspond per row to the values in the signal. Since they are pretty much on the same plane (not exactly but I don't care about the mild differences) I want a 2D plot of the points with the colors specifying the signal values.

Comment: ...so you're happy to drop the `z` data? I think you should look at interpolating your data so that it falls on a regular grid and then you can just use surf. Try [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) for the interpolation

Comment: The z data is fairly insignificant because the points were derived from an algorithm which takes the closest points to an xy plane (it's actually an optional choice in a GUI to chose between xy, xz and yz and the axis is chosen respectively). The differences between the different z values are negligible and I wanted a view of the 2-dimensional cross section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`surf` and `mesh` can be used when the points form a rectangular grid on the *xy* plane.

In the general case (points are arbitrarily placed), you can use [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html). For purposes of illustration, consider the following example `xyzp` and `signal`:

```
[x y] = ndgrid(-1:.01:1);
x = x+.3*y; %// example values which do not form a rectangular grid
z = x+y; %// example z as a function of x, y
xyzp = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];
signal = z(:)+x(:)-y(:); %// example values
```

Then

```
scatter3(xyzp(:,1), xyzp(:,2), xyzp(:,3), 1, signal, '.');
```

produces the following figure.

[image]

Since `scatter3` plots each point separately, the picture is not as smooth as it would be with `surf`. But this seems hard to improve if the coordinates do not a have any "structure" (as `surf` requires) .

Comment: Thank you, scatter3 is probably what I needed in my case. The problem was that I didn't know 'surf' requires a specific structure.